# Check Uncheck Checkbox column in Devexpres grid in Winform

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio-2010, devexpress

Hello developers I am using VS 2010 .I have a dev express grid in which I have a checkbox column.The problem is When i check the checkbox it gets checked but when i move to any other cell or column the checkbox gets automatically unchecked.Till now my code is as follows

```
 if (e.Column.ToString()=="Active" )
            {

                RepositoryItemCheckEdit edit = UserInfoGridView.GridControl.RepositoryItems.Add("CheckEdit") as RepositoryItemCheckEdit;


                column = e.Column;
                column.OptionsColumn.AllowSort = DevExpress.Utils.DefaultBoolean.False;
                column.Visible = true;
                column.VisibleIndex = 3;
                column.FieldName = "CheckMarkSelection";
                column.Caption = "Active";
                column.OptionsColumn.ShowCaption = true;
                column.OptionsColumn.AllowEdit = true;
                column.OptionsColumn.AllowSize = false;


                column.UnboundType = DevExpress.Data.UnboundColumnType.Boolean;

                column.ColumnEdit = edit;

            }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well I found the Answer.........What I did was this

```
   public frmLoad()
    {


        InitializeComponent();


        string DisplayQuery = "Select * from TableName";
         MasterDs = SqlHelper.ExecuteDataset(CommonClass.ConnectionString, CommandType.Text, DisplayQuery);
        MasterDs.Tables[0].Columns.Add("FLAG", typeof(string));

        MainGrid.DataSource = MasterDs.Tables[0];
        gridview.PopulateColumns();

        gridview.Columns["ID"].VisibleIndex = -1;
        gridview.Columns["FLAG"].VisibleIndex = -1;

        DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit selectnew = new DevExpress.XtraEditors.Repository.RepositoryItemCheckEdit();
        gridview.Columns["ColName"].ColumnEdit = selectnew;
        selectnew.NullText = "";
        selectnew.ValueChecked = "Y";
        selectnew.ValueUnchecked = "N";
        selectnew.ValueGrayed = "-";

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It may be because the datasource to witch the grid is bound is not being modified after the check uncheck action. Do you handle the `CellValueChanged` event of your view to change the property value of an object of your darasource ?

```
private void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.Name != "Active")
                return;

            var person = gridView1.GetFocusedRow() as Person;
            person.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value);
        }
```

Or, if you use a DataSet as a Datasource of your grid :

```
var id = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("IdColumnName");
var active = gridView1.GetFocusedRowCellValue("ActiveColumnName");

NorthwindDataSet.PersonsRow PersonsRow = 
    northwindDataSet1.Persons.FindByPersonID(id);

PersonsRow.ACTIVE= Convert.ToBoolean(active);
```

PS :  Not tested

Comment: When the cell value is changed the  **CellValueChanged** event is not fired

Comment: it will be fired after the cell loose focus, if you wish to do it before that, handle the CellValueChanging event.

Comment: The **CellValueChangedEvent** got fired but I am not able to navigate to last part of the Code Till now my code is `rivate void gridView1_CellValueChanged(object sender, CellValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Column.Name != "Active")
                return;

            var person = gridView1.GetFocusedRow();person.Active = Convert.ToBoolean(e.Value);
`

Comment: Is your grid datasource bound to an XPCollection, a List ... ?

Comment: it is bounded to an **Dataset** which gets filled from **SQLServer**

Comment: so, you need to update your dataset, I've edited my response to include how to do it

Comment: Try to get the Active value the same way you're getting the Id.

Comment: not getting anything ....Does the datatype of the table has to with any of these errors

Answer (score 0):

Try like this
        string DisplayQuery = "declare @Active bit; set @Active=0; select @Active as Active, * from TableName";

Answer (score 0):

The issue is probably caused by an incorrect underlying type for the column: it should be a `bool` to work out-of-the-box.

To set the type you may try something like:

```
MasterDs.Tables[0].Columns[0].DataType = typeof(bool);
```

Answer (score 0):

I am using Entity Framework 6.1 as the backend with ObjectContext.  I had set the database type to be tinyint, which maps to byte when entity framework updates the classes.

Changing the database type to bit and refreshing the entity objects creates the correct boolean type, after which the checkbox shows in DevExpress Winforms correctly.